# How to install nginx without the modules in RedHat

Tags: nginx, redhat, nginx-config, nginx-module

I install nginx using Yum following these steps:

1. `yum install epel-release`
2. `yum install nginx`

The following is the output of `nginx -V`:

```
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E'
```

How can I install nginx without the `--with*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that you must install nginx from source.
First download the tar.gz file from http://nginx.org/en/download.html then run the following command for compiling and installing:

1. `./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx  --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx  --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --user=nginx --group=nginx --build=CentOS --builddir=nginx-1.18.0 --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module`
   make sure to edit the version in builddir as your current version
2. run for compiling: `make`
3. for installing run `make install`

Comment: I saw this answer while trying to set up on an Ubuntu Docker container and I needed to `apt-get install -y libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev make gcc openssl libssl-dev` to get my modules to build correctly

Answer (score 0):

nginx is part of RHEL 8. Suggest installing that one: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/deploying_different_types_of_servers/setting-up-and-configuring-nginx_deploying-different-types-of-servers